# Grails modalbox plugin with draggable list from grails-ui (element visibility while dragging)

Tags: grails

I'm currently building a grails application with grails 1.3.7 (IDE: IntelliJ Ultimate 10.5), and I am using several plugins, mainly grails-ui 1.2.3 (+ its dependencies bubbling 2.1.4 and yui 2.8.2), modalbox 0.4 and spring security.

I encounter a problem when I use a modalbox (from the modalbox plugin), where I render a view with a draggable list in it from the grails-ui plugin. The problem is, that I can drag and drop both lists, but while dragging, the dragged list element is layered beneath the modalbox (and above the main site) so it is not visible while dragging. When I drop the element everything is fine again and all elements are visible. Now I wonder, if there is any possibility to push the element above the modalbox while dragging, or if anyone encountered this problem yet and knows a solution.

Many thanks in advance.
Dominic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a nap, I dug into the different js libraries used by the plugins and resolved the issue by adjusting the z-indices in the css file for the modalbox plugin.

Guess sometimes you just need to pause if you don't see the obvious ;)